# XML error: Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte

Tags: json, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-xml

I'm totally green to this and it's driving me nuts - it works for some data sets but not for others.

EDIT: It's looking like it's related to the number of records - somehow when teh number of records reaches a certain amount - maybe something like 250 - that's when it crashes the XML. Somehow the auto-incrementing ID primary key seems to be involved because I can see that when I add even 3 records when the ID column has gone into the 400's but all records are deleted it's still producing the same error but when I reset the ID back to zero - the same 3 records can be added and properly formatted in the XML body.

Mapping types: Int32 -> Byte System.Int32 -> System.Byte Destination path: FixtureDto.ExchangeType.ExchangeType.Id.Id Source value: 268

Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte.

The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.

[image]

```html
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace/>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Mapping types: Int32 -> Byte System.Int32 -> System.Byte Destination path: FixtureDto.ExchangeType.ExchangeType.Id.Id Source value: 268
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext() at WriteArrayOfFixtureDtoToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract ) at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiTypeAtTopLevel(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle originalDeclaredTypeHandle, Type graphType) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter writer, Object graph) at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content) at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.OverflowException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Convert.ToByte(Int32 value) at System.Int32.System.IConvertible.ToByte(IFormatProvider provider) at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider) at System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType) at AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeConverterMapper.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<GetConverter>b__0() at AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeConverterMapper.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper) at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context)
</StackTrace>
</InnerException>
</InnerException>
</Error>
```

Comment: I think I solved it.

Had int for ID field but had it as byte in Dto mapped field.

Comment: OK good.hope either you can put it as an `answer` or `delete` this post.

Comment: While I remain hopeful that this has indeed solved the issue once for all - this is the third time I have posted and come up with a 'resolution' to this issue in one guise or another so you will forgive me if I take a little while before rushing to conclude success before properly testing it over an satisfactory period of time

Comment: OK,take your time and hope you'll put your resolution as an answer :)

Comment: Updated with answer Sampath - probably should delete the previous two attempts to get to the bottom of it, one of which went unanswered and the second produced a workaround but wasnt a resolution at all.

Comment: OK,after `2 days` time you can `Accept` your `own Answer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved!

I had changed the datatype in my database class definition from byte to int but overlooked mirroring that same change in my equivalent data transfer mapped object.

This has been a thorn in the side for some time and the third attempt to get to the bottom of it, the previous attempt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430428/adding-unique-index-in-entity-framework-prevents-datatables-display-working) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39422237/reseeding-pk-on-lookup-table-fixed-datatables-not-showing-new-rows-but-what-cau?noredirect=1#comment66169315_39422237).

Eventually, through painstaking repeat testing I realised that it wasnt anything to do with adding indexes to tables, or bad data, or reseeding the ID auto-increment, but through the number of records in the database being limited in their display through the data transfer mapping mistake - ie, byte defined ID column limiting the number.

I have changed the dto definition to int to match the database and it now works beautifully scaling to more than 255 records at once as tested as it should do.
[image]